# Factorial function using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to implement the function below into one line of lambda code.

```
def fac(num):
    num = int(num)
    if num > 1:
        return num * fac(num - 1)
    else:
        return 1
```

I have constructed a lambda statement, but I keep getting syntax error:

```
z = lambda z: if (z > 1) z * (z-1) else 1
```

Comment: Don't use a lambda expression like this. You can't write an anonymous recursive function (at least, not without writing a second function to compute the fixed point first) in Python, and if you are going to assign the result of the lambda expression to a name, use a `def` statement instead.

Comment: Why use a lambda expression considering your function can be rewritten in one line as: `def fac(num): return num*fac(num-1) if num > 1 else 1`. This is preferred by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which states: "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you can't refer to a *global* name `z` when there is a local variable (the parameter) by the same name.

Thus, we will declare a *lambda* statement called `func` and use the `ternary` operator in the good way.

```
func = lambda z: z * func(z-1) if (z > 1) else 1
```

Output

```
> func(5)
120
```

Comment: So I can call the lambda function on itself much like the regular functions

Comment: @Yoko, yes, like `func(5)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a lambda expression where you really want a `def` statement. Lambda expressions produce *anonymous* functions. An anonymous function can't have a reference to itself, and recursion in Python relies on having such a refernce (usually in the form of a global or nonlocal variable).

---

That said, you *can* (using a bit of fancy lambda calculus) create a recursive function from an anonymous function. The trick is that your anonymous function will take *two* arguments: one is the "real" argument, the other is a reference to the function you want to call "recursively".

```
lambda n, f: n*f(n-1) if n else 1
```

There's no recursive call here; your anonymous function simply multiplies `n` by the return value of some function `f` called on `n-1` when `n` is greater than 0. (We're assuming that `n > 0`.) Your function doesn't know or care what `f` is; it just receives it as an argument.

The thing that gives us recursion is a single "universal" recursive function called `fix`. It takes your two-argument function and returns a single-argument function that calls your original function with its wrapper passed as the second argument:

```
def fix(g):
    def wrapper(n):
        return g(n, wrapper)
    return wrapper

fact = fix(lambda n, f: n*f(n-1) if n else 1)
```

Then

```
>>> fact(0)
1
>>> fact(3)
6
>>> fact(6)
720
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution as a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) is this one:

```
factorial = lambda n: 1 if n <= 1 else factorial(n - 1) * n
```

There are three problems with your code:

a) You are calling your function `z`, and your parameter `z` as well. You cannot do that if you are planning to call recursively the function itself, though you're not doing that in your code.

b) Recursive functions have a regular case and a base case. The base case, the end of recursion, is reached when the parameter goes down to 1, while in the regular case you call n * factorial(n - 1).

c) You used the [ternary operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) in an incorrect order, probably thinking in ternary operators present in C and others, in which you have: `<conditional-expression> ? <expression1> : <expression2>`, while in Python the syntax is `<expression1> if <conditional-expression> else <expression2>`.